# Swift 3 Local Notifications - Setting Automatic Timezone

Tags: uilocalnotification, swift3, nstimezone

So this worked flawlessly in Swift 2 but in Swift 3 it has problems:

```
func myNotifications () {
    let interval = 2.0
    var daysOut = 2.0
    let myArray =getArray()
    for i in 0..<myArray.count {
        let message = ("\(myArray[i])\n-\(myArray[i])")
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (60*60*24*daysOut))
        localNotification.alertBody = message
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
        localNotification.category = "Message"
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        daysOut += interval
    }

    let arrayCount = Double(myArray.count)
    let lastNotif_Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (60*60*24*interval*(quoteCount+1)))
    userPref_NSDefault.set(lastNotif_Date, forKey: "notification_EndDate")
}
```

Specifically, this line no longer works which is a big deal because I have users in multiple timezones and I want to make sure this works:

```
  localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
```

I get the error message:

> Type "NSTimeZone" has no member "autoUpdatingCurrent"

Any ideas? I tried "timeZone.automatic", ".automatic", and some other variations but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: `localNotification.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent`

Comment: UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS10

Comment: That worked, thanks. Strange, I would have thought if it were that simple that the auto-migration would have handled it. But if you're also saying that UILocalNotification is deprecated, am I going to run into bigger problems down the road?

Comment: No problem for now but you will need to change your code sometime down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `autoupdatingCurrent` != `autoupdatingCurrent`
2. `NSTimeZone` has been renamed to `TimeZone`

Comment: Yes, but his error message shows it with upper case U, he has a typo there.